# Calling delegate method in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, nstimer

I have an app where I use a subclass of UIView. In this subclass I create a NSTimer and in the selector method of the timer I call a method in the UIViewController that created an instance of the subclass. The problem I have is that the UIViewController is in a navigation controller and if the app segues away from the view controller in question the app crashes as soon as the timer tries to call a method in a nil view controller.

Here is my timer method in the UIView subclass

```
- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)localTimer
{
    secondCount++;
    __weak MySubclass *weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf.delegate updateTime:secondCount];
}
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalidate the timer when segues away from the view controller.

Use NSTimer `invalidate` method that stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop.

Comment: Is there a way to do so inside the subclass? I know I can prepare for a segue within a view controller. Can that also be done within a UIView Subclass?